# Calling dispose() or WindowEvent causes parent window to freeze

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel

I am currently attempting to add functionality to a program such that if a user closes a child window, it will also close the parent window that created it. I boot the starting program, select an option in the menu that will create the parent window, which then creates the child window. The program already has a `endProcess` function that prints something to the parent window so I figured it would be a good place to accomplish this task. Here is that function:

```
private synchronized void endProcess(Exec.FinishedEvent e) {
    exec.removeFinishedListener(this);
    exec = null;
    String str;
    if (e.getExitValue() != 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, exec, "Exec '"+e.getExec()+"' failed: return value: "+e.getExitValue(), JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        str = "Process FAILED [exit="+e.getExitValue()+"]: '"+e.getExec()+"'\n";
    } else
        str = "Process Done [exit="+e.getExitValue()+"]: '"+e.getExec()+"'\n";
    statusLabel.setText(str);
    outputTextArea.append("*****" + str);
    //this.dispose();
    //this.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
```

The bottom two commented out lines are what I have tried to add. (Two different ideas) Both of these work properly in that when I close the child window, the parent window also closes. However, it also freezes the original program window and will not respond to anything. I believe I am somehow calling some sort of kill function to the original program window as well? Thank you and let me know if I need to provide anything else!

To clarify...

Original Program = Window that first opens when booting the program

Parent Window = Command I run in the original program to produce the child window (I wish this one to close and NOT the Original Program when closing the child)

Child Window = The Window created from the Parent Window that I wish to also close the Parent Window upon the Child Window's closing.

Comment: @Sentry I'm sorry for the poor formatting, how did you make the improvements you did? Or could you point me to the instructions in stackOverflow?

Comment: In the upper right corner of the input box there is a question mark, which when clicked provides a link to http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help .
And no problem, you'll work it our over time and other will help until then.